# how to update custom control properties at design time immediately?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I created a custom Control which inherits from: Panel Control (using C# Class Library) then I used it inside a Form.
When I select any of the Control Properties (during design time), my custom control won’t update !
However if I close the Form and i reopen it; the changes will take place !

I want to have the Control updated when any of the Properties are changed.

Please find bellow my custom control code:

```
public class PersoCont : Panel
    {
        private int borderSize = 2;
        private Color borderColor = Color.DarkRed;
        private bool isBorder = true;
        private int paddingTopTitle = 0;
        private int paddingBorder = 0;

        public int padding_TopTitle
        {
            get { return paddingTopTitle; }
            set { paddingTopTitle = value; Invalidate(); }
        }

        public int padding_border
        {
            get { return paddingBorder; }
            set { paddingBorder = value; Invalidate(); }
        }

        public int border_size
        {
            get { return borderSize; }
            set { borderSize = value; Invalidate(); }
        }

        public Color border_color
        {
            get { return borderColor; }
            set { borderColor = value; Invalidate(); }
        }

        public bool is_border
        {
            get { return isBorder; }
            set { isBorder = value; Invalidate(); }
        }

        public PersoCont()
        {

        }

        protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.Controls.Find("xlblTitle", true).Length == 0)
            {
                if (isBorder == true)
                {
                    Label lblUp = new Label();
                    lblUp.Text = "";
                    lblUp.AutoSize = false;
                    lblUp.BackColor = borderColor;
                    int lblUpWidth = this.Width - (2 * paddingBorder) - (2 * borderSize);
                    lblUp.Size = new Size(lblUpWidth, borderSize);
                    lblUp.Location = new Point(borderSize + paddingBorder, paddingBorder);
                    lblUp.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Right;

                    Label lblDown = new Label();
                    lblDown.Text = "";
                    lblDown.AutoSize = false;
                    lblDown.BackColor = borderColor;
                    lblDown.Size = new Size(lblUpWidth, borderSize);
                    int lblDownTop = this.Height - paddingBorder - borderSize;
                    lblDown.Location = new Point(borderSize + paddingBorder, lblDownTop);
                    lblDown.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Right;

                    Label lblLeft = new Label();
                    lblLeft.Text = "";
                    lblLeft.AutoSize = false;
                    lblLeft.BackColor = borderColor;
                    int lblLeftHeight = this.Height - (2 * paddingBorder);
                    lblLeft.Size =new Size(borderSize,lblLeftHeight);
                    lblLeft.Location = new Point(paddingBorder, paddingBorder);
                    lblLeft.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Bottom;

                    Label lblRight = new Label();
                    lblRight.Text = "";
                    lblRight.AutoSize = false;
                    lblRight.BackColor = borderColor;
                    lblRight.Size = new Size(borderSize, lblLeftHeight);
                    int lblRightLeft = this.Width - paddingBorder - borderSize;
                    lblRight.Location = new Point(lblRightLeft, paddingBorder);
                    lblRight.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Right | AnchorStyles.Bottom;

                    this.Controls.Add(lblUp);
                    this.Controls.Add(lblDown);
                    this.Controls.Add(lblLeft);
                    this.Controls.Add(lblRight);
                }
            }
            base.OnHandleCreated(e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: A simple workaround: `if (this.DesignMode) this.FindForm()?.Refresh(); this.Invalidate();` (for custom controls only)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your help.

Initially I used the `OnPaint` event, but I really didn't like it because it would fire many times (I don't know why).

My problem was solved as follows:

I created a simple private method that will repaint (refresh the graphics data) according to all my properties. Now everything is working fine.

```
public class PersoCont2 : Panel
{
    Label lblUp = null;

    bool isBorder;
    Color borderColor;

    public bool is_border
    {
        get { return isBorder; }
        set { isBorder = value; Rearrange( ); }
    }

    public Color border_color
    {
        get { return borderColor; }
        set { borderColor = value; Rearrange( ); }
    }

    protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
    {
        Rearrange();
    }

    private void Rearrange( )
    {
        if( lblUp != null )
        {
            Controls.Remove( lblUp );
            lblUp = null;
        }
        if( is_border )
        {
            lblUp = new Label( );
            lblUp.BackColor = borderColor;
            // TODO: set properties
            // . . .
            lblUp.Location = new Point( 10, 10 );
            Controls.Add( lblUp );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Refresh` instead of `Invalidate` which only signals to the system that a repaint is needed, but won't actually do it: it will be a call to `Refresh` which will repaint it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.refresh

https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.update

You may test if the internal value has changed, before calling `Refresh` to do it (only if necessary):

```
public int padding_TopTitle
{
  get 
  { 
    return paddingTopTitle; 
  }
  set 
  { 
    if ( paddingTopTitle != value )
    {
      paddingTopTitle = value; 
      Refresh(); 
    }
  }
}
```

You may consider using [Framework Design Guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/) and [C# Naming Conventions](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/8a67c0/C-Sharp-coding-standards-and-naming-conventions/).

For example:

```
public int PaddingTopTitle
{
  get 
  { 
    return paddingTopTitle; 
  }
  set 
  { 
    if ( paddingTopTitle != value )
    {
      paddingTopTitle = value; 
      Refresh(); 
    }
  }
}
```

Or:

```
public int PaddingTopTitle
{
  get 
  { 
    return _PaddingTopTitle; 
  }
  set 
  { 
    if ( _PaddingTopTitle != value )
    {
      _PaddingTopTitle = value; 
      Refresh(); 
    }
  }
}
```

I personally prefer `_PaddingTopTitle` (or `_paddingTopTitle`) for private field of a property because `paddingTopTitle` is used for a method parameter as well as local var.

Therefore you may have for example : `BorderSize` and `_BorderSize` (or `_borderSize`).

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following code to rewrite panel control and get what you want.

```
public class MyPanel : Panel
{
    private Color colorBorder = Color.Transparent;

    public MyPanel()
        : base()
    {
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(
            new Pen(
                new SolidBrush(colorBorder), 6),
            e.ClipRectangle);
    }

    public Color BorderColor
    {
        get
        {
            return colorBorder;
        }
        set
        {
            colorBorder = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Result:
[image]

This behaviour however is a little bit awkward because it will only repaint after clicking the form designer.